# Limitar resultados de consulta a Firestore

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy cuidando las lecturas de la app, por lo que estoy limitando la cantidad de documentos que mando a leer de Firebase.

Quisiera leer (para iniciar) solamente 10 documentos de la siguiente forma:

```
Query query = database.Collection("Ventas").WhereEqualTo("Visible", true)
                                      .OrderBy("FechaHora").StartAt(0).EndAt(9);

                var response = await query.Get();
                var data = (QuerySnapshot)response;
                if (data.Documents.Count > 0)
                {
                    CantidadDocs = data.Documents.Count;
                } ...
```

Pero lo raro aca es que me devuelve cero documentos. Si realizo la consulta de esta forma me funciona sin problemas pero me devuelve todos los documentos `100`+:

```
Query query = database.Collection("Ventas").WhereEqualTo("Visible", true).OrderBy("FechaHora");
```

Al iniciar con las pruebas me genero un error con un URL que me redirecciono a Firebase para hacer un `índice compuesto` con `Visible` y `FechaHora`. Luego de la creacion del indice ya no me da error pero me devuelve cero (0) documentos.

Que sucede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque usaste los métodos de forma incorrecta.

Los métodos `StartAt`, `StartAfter`, `EndAt` y `EndBefore` tienen dos overloads: uno que recibe un argumento `DocumentSnapshot` y otro que acepta cualquier objeto. Este último es el que tu estás usando. El nombre del parámetro así como el hecho de que sea `java.lang.Object` en vez de `int`, deberían sugerirte que el valor que reciben no es un índice ni un offset.

Si lees la descripción del método detalladamente, entenderás cual es su uso correcto.

> Creates and returns a new Query that starts at the provided **fields**
> relative to the order of the query. The order of the field values must
> match the order of the order by clauses of the query.
>
> Params: **fieldValues** – The **field values** to start this query at, in order of the query's **order by**.
>
> Returns: The created Query.

Esto significa que tu consulta

```
database
    .Collection("Ventas")
    .WhereEqualTo("Visible", true)
    .OrderBy("FechaHora")
    .StartAt(0)
    .EndAt(9);
```

va a devolver los documentos donde "FechaHora" sea mayor o igual que `0` y menor o igual que `9`. La razón por la que devuelve cero documentos es porque ninguno cumple esa condición.

Para limitar los resultados de la consulta debes usar el método `limit()`, como menciona la [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#java)

```
database.Collection("Ventas").WhereEqualTo("Visible", true).OrderBy("FechaHora").Limit(10);
```

Luego si quieres los siguientes 10 puedes usar el `StartAfter` que recibe un `DocumentSnapshot` y pasarle el último documento que haya devuelto tu consulta anterior

```
Query baseQuery = database
    .Collection("Ventas")
    .WhereEqualTo("Visible", true)
    .OrderBy("FechaHora");

// 10 primeros
var response = await baseQuery.Limit(10).Get();
var data = (QuerySnapshot)response;
CantidadDocs = data.Documents.Count;
var lastDocument = data.Documents[CantidadDocs - 1];

// proximos 10
baseQuery.StartAfter(lastDocument).Limit(10);
```

Comment: Sinner, te agradezco tu respuesta tan detallada. Si lei la documentacion y la he seguido leyendo, de hecho hace como 2 horas probando entendi como se usa el StartAt, lo que me confundio fue que en la documentacion -- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors -- se uso un ejemplo de "Poblacion de un pais" (obviamente usaron cantidades para ese ejemplo), y eso me perdio ya que entendi lo que estaba necesitando. Te agradezco grandemente tu respuesta porque creo que no se me hubiera ocurrido el metodo para cargar los 10 extras.  o tal vez si, despues de unos 2 meses.